# Merging identical tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, geom-tile

I use `geom_tile()` together with `geom_text` from `ggplot2` to generate basically a table:

[image]

Two factors (X and Y) are plotted on the x-axis (resulting in two columns of tiles). Levels of factor Y are nested within factor X. Therefore, multiple identical tiles for factor X are plotted (one per level of factor Y). Is there a way to "merge" the tiles of factor X to larger tiles with the text occurring only once per tile? I am also open for approaches using other functions than `geom_tile()` to achieve this.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(id = c(1:4, 1:4),
                  factor = c(rep("X", times = 4), rep("Y", times = 4)),
                  value = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

ggplot(dat, aes(y = id, x = factor)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

`y = id` must be preserved.

### Edit 1

In my actual data id is a factor:

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = factor(c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")),
                  factor = c(rep("X", times = 4), rep("Y", times = 4)),
                  value = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
```

### Edit 2

A reprex that produces the problem of multiple "merged" cells per level of factor with code provided by Allan Cameron:

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = factor(c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")),
                  factor = rep(c('X', 'Y'), each = 4),
                  value  = c('A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'))

dat %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(factor(id))) %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(chunk = data.table::rleid(value)) %>%
  group_by(factor, chunk, value) %>%
  summarise(y = n()) %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(height = y) %>%
  mutate(y = (cumsum(y) + cumsum(lag(y, 1, 0)))/2 + 0.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = factor)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = height), color = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_y_continuous('id', breaks = seq_along(unique(dat$id)),
                     labels = levels(factor(dat$id)))
```

Output:

[image]

The rows containing "C" should be merged for each factor.

### Edit 3

A subset of my real data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 8L,
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 8L),
                                     levels = c("n374", "n673", "n139", "n2015",
                                                "n344", "n36", "n467", "n76"),
                                     class = "factor"),
                      factor = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                                           3L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                         levels = c("phylum", "class", "genus"),
                                         class = "factor"),
                      value = c("Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria",
                                "Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria",
                                "Bacteroidetes", "Proteobacteria",
                                "Bacteroidetes", "Proteobacteria",
                                "Alphaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria",
                                "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria",
                                "Cytophagia", "Betaproteobacteria",
                                "Chitinophagia", "Betaproteobacteria",
                                "Sphingomonas", "Aquabacterium",
                                "Dongia", "Sphingomonas", "Chryseolinea",
                                "unidentified", "unidentified","Sphaerotilus")),
                 row.names = c(NA, -24L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This produces the following output with the code from the EDIT by Allan Cameron:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What I want:

- For factor phylum: The two areas for Proteobacteria should be merged.
- For factor class: The two areas for Betaproteabacteria should be merged.
- For factor genus: The two areas for Sphingomonas should be merged.
- For factor genus: The two areas for "unidentified" should not be merged, since thy are nested in different levels of factor phylum and class.

### Edit 4

The latest code by Allan Cameron still causes "lower level" tiles to merge when they were not nested in the same "higher level" tile. This affects the value "unidentified":

[image]

This can be reproduced with the following data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L,
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L),
                                     levels = c("OTU_374", "OTU_673", "OTU_139",
                                                "OTU_344", "OTU_36", "OTU_467"),
                                     class = "factor"),
                      factor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                         levels = c("phylum", "class", "genus"),
                                         class = "factor"),
                      value = c("Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria",
                                "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes",
                                "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes",
                                "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria",
                                "Alphaproteobacteria", "Cytophagia",
                                "Betaproteobacteria", "Chitinophagia",
                                "Sphingomonas", "unidentified", "Sphingomonas",
                                "Chryseolinea", "unidentified", "unidentified")),
                 row.names = c(NA, -18L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

"Lower level" tiles should not merge, if they were already separated by a "higher level" tile.

Comment: Read about https://gt.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `geom_col`:

```r
ggplot(dplyr::count(dat, value, factor), aes(y = n, x = factor)) +
  geom_col(color = "black", fill = NA, position = 'stack', width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

But a more general solution using `geom_tile` would be to calculate the central point and height of each tile, mapping the latter to the `height` aesthetic.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(factor(id))) %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(chunk = data.table::rleid(value)) %>%
  group_by(factor, chunk, value) %>%
  summarise(y = n()) %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(height = y) %>%
  mutate(y = (cumsum(y) + cumsum(lag(y, 1, 0)))/2 + 0.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = factor)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = height), color = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_y_continuous('id', breaks = seq_along(unique(dat$id)),
                     labels = levels(factor(dat$id)))
```

[image]

This also allows non-consecutive blocks to be merged, for example, if your data is

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1:7, 1:7),
                  factor = rep(c('X', 'y'), each = 7),
                  value  = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B',
                             'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'B'))
```

Then you would get

[image]

So that the IDs are always matched to the correct value and ID ordering takes precedence over cell merging.

---

**EDIT**

With some of the actual data now available, and the new information from the OP we can do:

```r
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(factor = paste0(factor, '_value')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = factor, values_from = value) %>% 
  arrange(phylum_value, class_value, genus_value) %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id, id)) %>%
  group_by(phylum_value) %>%
  mutate(phylum_chunk = cur_group_id()) %>%
  group_by(phylum_value, class_value) %>%
  mutate(class_chunk = cur_group_id()) %>%
  group_by(phylum_value, class_value, genus_value) %>% 
  mutate(genus_chunk = cur_group_id()) %>%
  pivot_longer(phylum_value:genus_chunk, names_sep = '_', 
               names_to = c('factor', '.value'))

dat2 %>%
  group_by(factor, chunk, value) %>%
  summarise(y = n()) %>%
  mutate(factor = factor(factor, c('phylum', 'class', 'genus'))) %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(height = y) %>%
  mutate(y = (cumsum(y) + cumsum(lag(y, 1, 0)))/2 + 0.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = factor)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = height), color = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_y_continuous('id', breaks = seq_along(levels(dat2$id)),
                     labels = levels(dat2$id))
```

[image]

Comment: Your second approach is almost what I need and works perfectly with my code example. Thanks for taking your time! However, with my real data, for each level of my factors multiple “merged cells” are plotted. Additionally, the y axis is shorter than the stacked tiles. In my real data, “id” is not numeric but a factor. Sorry for that mistake! I updated my example accordingly. Could that be the reason for the unexpected behavior? If not, I will try to create a new reprex.

Comment: I’ve added a new reprex to my initial question. One problem was that my real input data.frame contained duplicate rows. This had caused the “shorter” y-axis. However, I still have the problem of multiple “merged cells”. Can you please help me understand the reason for this behavior?

Comment: No, I do not want to merge cells across rows. The two cells containing "C" in each of the columns should be merged. Sorry, my reprex might be confusing because both factors have the same levels. I will update it.

Comment: The order of the elements on the y axis is arbitrary. Levels of factor Y that have to be merged are always nested within one value of factor X, so merging for factor Y should still be possible if the order of the elements on the y axis is flexible.

Comment: The `geom_col` solution does not preserve the id values unfortunately . Although the order of the elements on the y axis does not matter, it is necessary that the ids are used to generate the y axis. The reason is, that I want to use `aplot` to merge this plot with another plot that has the same values on the y axis. The order of the values on the y axis for this second plot will be according to the plot we are discussing here.

Comment: The nestedness is also not considered by the `geom_col` solution.

Comment: Many thanks for the update! This works perfect for the first column (X) but in the second (and in my real dataset third and so on) column the merging still only works when two cells are adjacent. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I have added a subset of my real data (EDIT 3). Would you mind taking a look at it again?

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem with the inconsistent nestedness is however not in my data. You can see that when using my initial code that did not do merging. Also, when looking at e. g. n76 with `subset(dat, id == "n76") `,  you can see that the levels for class and genus are wrong in the result you suggested.

Comment: This is super close. There is still one minor problem though. Please see my edit #4.

Comment: @empetrum I have now fixed this. The Q&A is getting very messy here with all the additions caused by edge cases as you discover them. It may be worth asking a new question if this update doesn't quite work for you. I will delete all my comments from above, which are also messing things up considerably.

Comment: Your latest code does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for taking your time! I was not expecting this to get that complex.